# how can I change environment variables when running rspec for ruby?

Tags: ruby, rspec, environment-variables

I have several ruby scripts and test them with rspec.

I put my environments in a env.rb file (for now) so I can access them locally and in production put them in the config variables.

But when I run rspec, I would like different environment variables.  Two use cases:

- I run Twilio, so I want to be able to change the SID used to their Test Credentials
- I store things in a database as a service, and want to have a separate test database

Comment: You should just use the environment variable in your test suite.  So initialize a Twillio client with your other credentials instead of your production credentials.

Comment: How do I set environment variables in the test suite ?  Explicitly in the context?  I guess that makes sense. Thanks b

Answer (score 6):

You can

- set ENV vars explicitly in the context with `ENV["FOO_BAR"] = "baz"`
- check `Rails.env.test?` in your initializers to setup twilio and other clients with test specific opts
- have a file with all your env setup for test and then use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)

I personally prefer to use ENV vars only when creating objects and then passing the env var value to the constructor, so I can test the object class without caring about ENV, and I can test the object that initializes the other object with the env var, by just asserting the creation used the env var.

So you'd change something like

```
class Client
  def initialize
    @restclient = RestClient::Resource.new(ENV["API_URL"])
  end
end
```

to

```
class Client
  def initialize(url)
    @restclient = RestClient::Resource.new(url)
  end
end
```

and have whatever is initializing that instance to then pass the value of the env var

```
def fetch_content
  client = Client.new(ENV["API_URL"])
  # ...
end
```

this way you can test the `Client` class without caring about the env var by just passing any url, and then can test the class that instantiates the `client` as

```
it "uses client" do
  ENV["API_URL"] = "foo.com"
  expect(Client).to receive(:new).with(ENV["API_URL"])  
  subject.fetch_content
end
```

one problem with updating the env var is that the change persist throughout the rest of the test suite, and may cause problems if you don't expect it to be there in some tests, in these cases you can mock the value with

```
expect(ENV).to receive(:[]).with("API_URL").and_return("foo.com")
```

Comment: Is I set in context I would need to repeat if tested it multiple context?  I don't use Rails so how does #2 play?  I didn't follow your last paragraph. Is that referencing#1?

Comment: You should ideally repeat the setup in an `before(:each)`. Notice that one of the peculiarities of using env vars is that once you set it on the test all the other tests will have that value, which might be harmless but it's good to keep in mind if you see tests that pass when run alone but fail when running with the rest of the suite

Comment: Even though you've said not to use the direct binding to ENV, I quite like it. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 4):

Since ENV is global state you want to reset the value after each spec to avoid it leaking between specs:

```
describe 'enabled?' do
  around do |example|
    env_value_before = ENV['MIXPANEL_ENABLED']
    ENV['MIXPANEL_ENABLED'] = env_value
    example.run
    ENV['MIXPANEL_ENABLED'] = env_value_before
  end

  context 'when ENV not set' do
    let(:env_value) { nil }

    it 'returns true' do
      expect(subject.enabled?).to eq(true)
    end
  end

  context 'when ENV is set' do
    let(:env_value) { '1' }

    it 'returns false' do
      expect(subject.enabled?).to eq(false)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: +2 to this answer. It is tidy, and does a great job of preserving the existing value of the ENV var after the test.

Answer (score 4):

You can mock ENV to return a value. This is a super-clean one-liner that ensures that nothing can leak out to other tests:

```
context 'when LOG_LEVEL is DEBUG' do
  before { allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).with('LOG_LEVEL').and_return('debug') }
  ...
```

That works great if your code only looks at one ENV var. If it needs other vars that are not of interest to this test, you can allow those to call original: (although this starts to feel a bit cludgy)

```
context 'when LOG_LEVEL is DEBUG' do
  before do
    allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).and_call_original
    allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).with('LOG_LEVEL').and_return('debug')
  end
```

Comment: This approach works just as well with `.recieve(:fetch)` if that's your coding style. You DO need to match the method your code actually uses. If you're sloppy and use both methods, you can mock both.

Answer (score 0):

In case you often need to stub multiple environment variables in the same context this helper method might be used:

```
def stub_env_variable(env_variable, new_value)
  unless RSpec::Mocks.space.registered?(ENV)
    # With the condition it allows us to call this helper multiple times for different env variables
    # in the same context.
    #
    # Allowing to return original ENV variables which are not yet stubbed:
    allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).and_call_original
  end

  allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).with(env_variable).and_return(new_value)
end
```

It allows to set multiple environment variables in the same context but in a cleaner way, for example:

```
before do
  stub_env_variable("VAR_1", 123)
  stub_env_variable("VAR_2", false)
  stub_env_variable("VAR_3", "qwerty")
end
```

Inspired by the answer from @David Hempy.