# RSpec - Allow any instance of ENV to receive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, deface

I'm testing controller with view overwritten with deface (no DSL) and I have a problem...

In deface file I'm fetching parameter from `ENV` and because of that my tests are failing.

Deface file:

```
if ENV.fetch('something', nil).present?
  Deface::Override.new(...)
end
```

Rspec:

```
allow(ENV).to receive(:fetch).with("something").and_return('value')
```

Question: How can I set value globally so `ENV` will be available in deface file ?

Note: `allow_any_instance_of` doesn't work for `ENV`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560868/how-can-i-change-environment-variables-when-running-rspec-for-ruby

Comment: You can also stub a constant in RSpec with `stub_const`.