# Defining a env variable when executinga Rake task as part of a RSpec specification

Tags: rspec, rake

In RSpec, I'm specifying the behavior I expect a Rake task to have. The task is defined in the Rakefile located at the root or the project.

From my understanding, the following code runs the task as running `rake xml:export` in the console.

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe 'xml:export' do
  load 'Rakefile'
  let(:task) { Rake::Task['xml:export'] }

  it '' do
    task.execute
  end
end
```

However, The task requires to be run as `rake xml:export date=2020-01-01` since it expects the `ENV['date']` to be passed in.

How can I provide the date when executing the task in my spec?

I have tried `system('rake xml:export date=2020-01-01')` instead of `task.execute` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to define your date using the hook `before` in Rspec ? (cf: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec%2FCore%2FHooks:before )

You could define your date as following for example :

```
      before do
        ENV["date"] = "2020-01-01"
      end

      it '' do
        task.execute
      end
```

However, the previous example is not the most recommended, here is an interesting answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27586912/11018979)

or

```
      before do
        allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).with("date").and_return("2020-01-01")
      end

      it '' do
        task.execute
      end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I don't remember why I asked the question.